# Javascript - DOM Style Display Works But Resets Itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a fairly basic form that is designed to take multiple inputs, calculate the stored variables and output the results. Really basic stuff, I've done it plenty of times before just not with JS.

At the moment though I'm not worried about the calculations as I haven't got that far yet. I have successfully got the variables to store their respective values and now I am trying the use DOM Style Display to hide the input div and display the results div on click of the submit button.

*html (button only)*

```
<div class="col text-center pt-4">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark text-center" id="btn-calculate" onclick="calculate.js">Calculate</button>
</div>
```

*css*

```
#form-input {
display: block;
}

#form-output {
display: none;
}
```

*javascript*

```
document.getElementById('btn-calculate').onclick = function() {

document.getElementById('form-input').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('form-output').style.display = 'block';

}
```

There are two ways I have done this. The first, without the first line of JS, executed straight away on page load and sat there happily as I required. However, I needed this to happen on clicking of the aforementioned button, not on page load. The second was as written above. It executes as required on click but after around 500ms the page resets as if I had never clicked the button.

I have tried `stop ()` at the end of the JS to no avail.

Finally, prior to tonight, I have never tried my hand at JS only a little JQuery at the hand of a tutorial. I may have bitten off a fair chunk but that's just who I am.

I not looking for anyone to hold my hand and write the code for me, but just for a little light to be shed or where I've obviously gone wrong in my rookie approach. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `submit` button will **post the form** when you click it, causing the page to reload. If you don't want that, don't use a `submit` button.

Comment: You don't need `onclick="calculate.js"`. You register an onclick handler later. If you want to declare it here, then you need to pass a function, not a script file.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers.